# What's the different between task_basic_info.resident_size and task_basic_info. phys_footprint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, virtual-memory

Is phys_footprint means the total memory alloc by App,resident_size means the resident part of memory alloc by App?I found some times resident_size is bigger than phys_footprint,that's why?

Comment: You need to upload code here. Without required info, no one will understand what you are talking about

Comment: It might be related to how OSX manages the memory, I'm not sure but maybe the phys_footprint contains the internal and compressed memory sizes as well.